# How to set a value in AJAX success function after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

How to set a value to `Textarea` control in `AJAX success` function after reloading the page?

by below code I am getting a value in page view i.e, "Create.cshtml"

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".setLang").on("click", function (event) {
      var txt = $("#About").val();
      var langge = $(this).attr("data-lang");

      if (txt != null && txt != "" && langge != null && langge != "") {
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url :  "@Url.Action("Translation", "Home")",
          traditional: true,
          data: { text: txt, language: langge },
          success: successFunc,
          error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data){
          alert(data);
          $("#About").val(data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

but when I am trying to set it like below, its cant taking in 'textarea'

```
function successFunc(data) {
  alert(data);
  $("#About").val(data);
}
```

mean while in shared view some code running like below i,e, "_Layout.cshtml"

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var lang = MultiLanguageDemo.Cookies.getCookie("LangForMultiLanguageDemo");
    $(".setLang[data-lang='" + lang + "'] img").addClass("active-lang");
    $(".setLang").on("click", function (event) {
      var lang = $(this).attr("data-lang");                  
      MultiLanguageDemo.Cookies.setCookie("LangForMultiLanguageDemo", lang, 30);    
      location.reload(true);
    })
  });
</script>
```

the text area is

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("About", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.About, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.About, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it alerting `data`?

Comment: yes, its alerting data in success function.

Comment: @asma If you refresh the page then also you want to so the value from success method into `textarea`?

Comment: yes, I tried to set it into coockie but when and where have to get it?

Comment: @asma Please share the response data of AJAX success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 if(localStorage.getItem("textareamessage") != null){
   $("#About").val(localStorage.getItem("textareamessage"));
 }

  $(".setLang").on("click", function (event) {
    var txt = $("#About").val();
    var langge = $(this).attr("data-lang");

    if (txt != null && txt != "" && langge != null && langge != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url :  "@Url.Action("Translation", "Home")",
        traditional: true,
        data: { text: txt, language: langge },
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
      });

      function successFunc(data){
        alert(data);
        localStorage.setItem("textareamessage", data);
        $("#About").val(data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I've used `localStorage` instead of `cookies`.

Please share the response data of AJAX success.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: your answer is exact what i want...thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using (if you use html)

```
$("#About").html(data);
```

or

```
$("#About").append(data);
```

Also have you checked the data is not null? Because what I see you call the function without passing any data.

Maybe doing like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#About").html(data);
}
```

Or

```
success: succesFunc(data)
```

Sven

Comment: in success function data coming from controller action methode. and can getting it in suuccess function. and also can set the data by $("#About").val(data);..but the thing is master _Layout view is running some code by which its cant..

Comment: Also please note that success and error are deprecated. Please use done() and fail(). Can you show some of your html for reference?

Comment: html reference like? u mean controls?

Comment: I mean the about <div> or the html page where you want to set a value to.